# confusion on swift3 arc4random_uniform

Tags: xcode, swift3

I'm confused with using `arc4random_uniform` in Swift3. My understanding is that I can set the max and min values that can be produced with `Int(arc4random_uniform(max value) + min starting value)` so that `Int(arc4random_uniform(5) + 1)` should give a value between 1 and 5.

My code below however sometimes gives out a value more that my max and less than my min.

```
var whateverNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(100) + 50);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want random number between 50 to 100 then you code should be

```
var whateverNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(50) + 50)
```

Comment: I don't have my mac with me now but I'll try this later thanks.

Comment: I've only been able to try this today, but the code above still gave me a 3. So I'm not sure if there's anything wrong with Swift 3 or xcode. Anyway I'll try a few more things and then maybe close this question if I can. I'm new to the forums.

Answer (score -1):

Try this to get random number between 50 and 100:

```
int minimumValue = 50;
int maximumValue = 100;
int randomNumber = minimumValue + arc4random() % (maximumValue - minimumValue);
```